# How does --max-status-checks-per-second work?

Tags: python, slurm, snakemake, rate-limiting

Is `--max-status-checks-per-second` a limit on the number of queries snakemake makes to *each* job each second, or a limit on the total number of queries snakemake makes amongst all jobs each second? I.e., if `--max-status-checks-per-second` is set to the default value of 10 and there are 500 jobs running, does it take snakemake no fewer than 50 seconds to talk to check in on each job?

Answer (score 1):

`Snakemake` uses [`ratelimiter`](https://pypi.org/project/ratelimiter/) behind the scenes for this. If `--max-status-checks-per-second` is set to 10, then there will be no more than 10 requests sent per second, hence for 500 jobs this means it will take about 50 seconds to check all jobs.

Setting a higher number request checks is possible, but one would need to check with their cluster administration on what is the allowed maximum.

The relevant [snakemake code](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/blob/fd5daaeff070f9987dba411a0f5262c533a2f666/snakemake/executors/__init__.py#L1249-L1278).